# How to access variables from higher environments

Tags: r

```
f <- function(x, y, z) {
    lapply(as.list(match.call()[-1]), eval)
}

f(x=2, z=3)
```

The output is as expected:

```
$x
[1] 2

$z
[1] 3
```

However, when this function is wrapped into another one, it fails.

```
g <- function(a) {
    f(x=a, z= 3)
}

g(2)
```

The error message:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found
```

Apparently, the `eval` function only looks in the parent environment, not in higher environments. In debug mode, it works as expected:

```
> g <- function(a) {
+   browser()
+   f(x=a, z= 3)
+ }
> g(2)
Called from: g(2)
Browse[1]> a
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taken from `?eval` examples:

```
f <- function(x, y, z) {
  e1 <- parent.frame()
  lapply(as.list(match.call()[-1]), eval, envir = e1)
}

f(x=2, z=3)

g <- function(a) {
  f(x=a, z= 3)
}

g(5)
```

It seems you need to specifically define the parent environment.

Comment: Yep, this does the trick, thx! Are you also going to the eRum2018?

Comment: Answer [here](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/193#issuecomment-388617432)